# Change (.load) HTML content when click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to develop a div that when clicked on any of the buttons alters the entire site content. But I can only click once, clicking new content does not change. Can anyone help me please?

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div id="include">
     &nbsp;       
  </div>
</section>
```

JQuery:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("div[data-feature='1']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/1.html"); 
    });
    $("div[data-feature='2']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/2.html"); 
    });
    $("div[data-feature='3']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/3.html"); 
    });
    $("div[data-feature='4']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/4.html"); 
    });
    $("div[data-feature='5']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/5.html"); 
    });
    $("div[data-feature='6']").click(function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/6.html"); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: you need to bind event to new element

Comment: If none of the answers have helped or you are still having trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and simply your code like

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('click', 'div[data-feature]', function(e){
      $("#include").load("folder/" + $(this).attr('data-feature') + ".html"); 
    });
  });
```

This will attach an event handler for all **current** and **future**(loaded) `div[data-feature]` elements

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `live` instead of `bind`. I'll explain below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('body').on('click', 'div[data-feature]', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var feature = $this.data('feature');
            $("#include").load("folder/" + feature + ".html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The difference is: your event is being added to the `body`. Think about this: when you click a button, you are also clicking in every parent element of that button, including the `body`. jQuery knows which element triggered that click and, when the body receives the click, it will check if the element which triggered the click is a `div[data-feature]`, if it is, that function will be executed.

The problem with direct bind, in this case, is that your element must exist so the function can be appended to it.